# Angularjs add controller dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, single-page-application

It looks like this questions already asked few times but there is no correct answer to it.

my case: i'm loading a template (with html and script) init to div using ajax (not using angular routing temple for some reason).

**index.html (main)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Web</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <div class="dynamic-content" >
                <!-- Loading content Here -->
            </div>
            <button ng-click="loadTemplate()">Load Template</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            angular.module('app', [])
            .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.someData = {};
                $scope.loadTemplate = function() {
                    ....
                    //AJAX to get the templet.html
                    //and load it into .dynamic-content
                    //then applying scope();                  
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**template.html (template)**

```
<div ng-controller="TempCtrl">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <h3>{{total}}</h3>
    <p>Testing the total</p>
    <button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
</div>

<script>
    console.log('begin')
    angular.module('app')
    .controller('TempCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.total = 0;
        console.log('inside')
        $scope.update = function () {
            $scope.total += 1;
        };
    });
    console.log('end')
</script>
```

when i click the button `Load Template` it loads the `template.html` file in to container but i'm getting error

> Error: [[ng:areq](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq)] Argument 'TempCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

though its being added to app controllers.

How can i add controllers dynamically and get it work with dynamic html nodes

**DEMO HERE**  https://plnkr.co/edit/EAa9Md36hDzpQ1BgIQKg?p=preview

Comment: So you're loading ajax that attempts to add a new controller to your existing module, and the "begin" and "end" are showing up in your console, indicating that the script is being executed?

Comment: Have you tried just putting the script before the HTML portion of the template?

Comment: Yes the console is showing `begin` and `end` but not `inside`

Comment: @Dave Yes i tried like that, but same error

Comment: @JAG why don't you place `TempCtrl` in some `js` file & load it on initial page by referring it on `index.html`

Comment: "You cannot add controllers, services, directives, etc after an application [bootstraps](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)." You can search for *lazy loading controllers* or *loading controllers after bootstrap* to find some hacky ways.

Comment: @PankajParkar i have 50+ files like template.html so cant load all at once

Comment: @sabithpocker I checked those lazy loading methods but non of them relate to this scenario. they work with router-template-resolve

Comment: So this scenario is neither supported by angular nor is there any ready hacks available. I would suggest you to change the approach as moving in this direction is either a deadend or will make things harder as you advance :)

Comment: Actually this might do the trick:  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2553-loading-angularjs-components-after-your-application-has-been-bootstrapped.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This blog describes how to fiddle with angular to force it to load additional controllers after it has been bootstrapped:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2553-loading-angularjs-components-after-your-application-has-been-bootstrapped.htm

Of course, this is completely unsupported, and could be broken by changes to angular at any time.

But, here is an updated version of your code using this method:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.config(
  function($controllerProvider, $provide, $compileProvider) {
    // Since the "shorthand" methods for component
    // definitions are no longer valid, we can just
    // override them to use the providers for post-
    // bootstrap loading.
    console.log("Config method executed.");
    // Let's keep the older references.
    app._controller = app.controller;
    app._service = app.service;
    app._factory = app.factory;
    app._value = app.value;
    app._directive = app.directive;
    app.controller = function(name, constructor) {
      console.log("controller...");
      console.log(name);
      console.dir(constructor);
      $controllerProvider.register(name, constructor);
      return (this);
    };
    // Provider-based service.
    app.service = function(name, constructor) {
      $provide.service(name, constructor);
      return (this);
    };
    // Provider-based factory.
    app.factory = function(name, factory) {
      $provide.factory(name, factory);
      return (this);
    };
    // Provider-based value.
    app.value = function(name, value) {
      $provide.value(name, value);
      return (this);
    };
    // Provider-based directive.
    app.directive = function(name, factory) {
      $compileProvider.directive(name, factory);
      return (this);
    };
  });
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http, $compile) {
  $scope.someData = {};
  $scope.loadTemplate = function() {
    $http.get("template.html")
      .then(function(r) {
        // load in the html, including the script, which will be executed
        $(".dynamic-content").html(
          r.data
        );
        // compile the loaded html into an actual template and put it back where it was
        $(".dynamic-content").html($compile($(".dynamic-content").html())($scope));
      })
  }
});
```

Note that I used jQuery to place the HTML into the DOM, causing the script to execute, then to grab the HTML back out of the DOM so it could be compiled, after which I placed it back in the DOM again.

Also, there is an undefined variable in your template.html, so I updated it to look like this:

```
<script>
    console.log('begin')
    angular.module('app')
    .controller('TempCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.total = 0;
        console.log('inside')
        $scope.update = function () {
            $scope.total += 1;
        };
    });
    console.log('end')
</script>

<div ng-controller="TempCtrl">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <h3>{{total}}</h3>
    <p>Testing the total</p>
    <button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
</div>
```

Here is a working plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/cB5N05

Comment: Perfect. this is exactly what i want.. Thanks Dave.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated [Dave's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467697/5673489) example with angular components support**

```
app.config(
  function ($controllerProvider, $provide, $compileProvider) {

    var app = angular.module('app');

    // Let's keep the older references.
    app._controller = app.controller;
    app._service = app.service;
    app._factory = app.factory;
    app._value = app.value;
    app._directive = app.directive;
    app._component = app.component;

    // Provider-based controller.
    app.controller = function (name, constructor) {
        $controllerProvider.register(name, constructor);
        return ( this );
    };
    // Provider-based service.
    app.service = function (name, constructor) {
        $provide.service(name, constructor);
        return ( this );
    };
    // Provider-based factory.
    app.factory = function (name, factory) {
        $provide.factory(name, factory);
        return ( this );
    };
    // Provider-based value.
    app.value = function (name, value) {
        $provide.value(name, value);
        return ( this );
    };
    // Provider-based directive.
    app.directive = function (name, factory) {
        $compileProvider.directive(name, factory);
        return ( this );
    };
    // Provider-based component.
    app.component = function (name, options) {
        $compileProvider.component(name, options);
        return ( this );
    };

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try loading the templates controller in the index.html, instead of in the template.html, that way it is already existing when the markup is looking for it.
In index.html script portion:

```
  angular.modules('app', [])
        .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.someData = {};
            $scope.loadTemplate = function() {
                ....
                //AJAX to get the templet.html
                //and load it into .dynamic-content
                //then applying scope();                  
            }
        }).controller('TempCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.total = 0;
    console.log('inside')
    $scope.update = function () {
        total += total;
    };
});
```

EDIT:
This is when having multiple JS files that reference the app module would be handy, that way each file is owning a controller.

Comment: my question is how to add **dynamic controllers** not how to get this example work..

Comment: I'm just curious now, what is the benefit you want to receive from this?

Comment: like i mentioned.. i have 50+ template files with each template has its own controller(s). so cant put them all in one file and load at once

Comment: anyhow i found a solution and updated my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/EAa9Md36hDzpQ1BgIQKg?p=preview